# I face casting error while trying filter with Mongoose. Please! check

Tags: typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

it's my first question here so, I hope I hit the context and describe this as well as I could.

I have that function that provides my API handler(controller/route handler) with all the fancy stuff of (filtering/sorting/pagination) but, it works with 2 endpoints perfectly and doesn't work with that particular endpoint.

The code of that service function:

```
export async function paginate<ModelInterface>(
  Model: mongoose.Model<ModelInterface>,
  {
    filters = {},
    limit = 10,
    page = 1,
    sort = {},
  }: PaginateOptions<ModelInterface> = {}
) {
  try {
    const skip = (page - 1) * limit;
    const list = await Model.find(filters)
      .sort(sort)
      .skip(skip || 0)
      .limit(limit || 0);
    const total = await Model.count(filters);
    const count = list.length;
    const hasMore = count + skip < total;
    const thisPage = page;
    const nextPage = hasMore ? page + 1 : null;
    const lastPage = Math.ceil(total / limit);
    return { list, total, count, hasMore, thisPage, nextPage, lastPage };
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

I started working on the project and it was working with this Endpoint (users).

Here's the user.service:

```
export async function findUsers(options: PaginateOptions<UserDocument> = {}) {
  const allowPartialMatch = ["company", "email", "website", "name"];
  console.log(options);
  try {
    const filters =
      options.filters &&
      Object.entries(options.filters).reduce(
        (ret, [key, value]) => ({
          ...ret,
          [key]: allowPartialMatch.includes(key)
            ? { $regex: value, $options: "i" }
            : value,
        }),
        {}
      );
    const query = { ...options, filters };
    return await paginate<UserDocument>(UserModel, query);
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

and user.controller which will be applied to the route handler:

```
export async function getAllUsersHandler(
  req: Request<{}, {}, {}, { filters: string; page: string; sort: string }>,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) {
  try {
    const { query } = req;

    const filters = JSON.parse(
      query.filters || "{}"
    ) as FilterQuery<UserDocument>;
    const sort = JSON.parse(query.sort || "{}") as {
      [key: string]: SortValues;
    };
    const data = await findUsers({
      filters,
      page: parseInt(query.page) || 1,
      sort,
    });
    return res.json(data);
  } catch (error: any) {
    next(error);
  }
}
```

Once I started working on the project my task was working on another endpoint with the same structure and I applied the same code for another endpoint with the modifications and It worked perfectly.
but for this endpoint, it Gave me this Error which I can't solve. Please! help.

redeem.service:

```
export async function listRedeems(
  options: PaginateOptions<RedeemDocument> = {}
) {
  const allowPartialMatch = ["amount", "user", "transaction_id", "approved"];
  console.log(options);
  try {
    // FIXME: it Produce a "Cast Error" complaining About "i" property Type.
    // ERR-TRACE: https://noncebloxworkspace.slack.com/files/U02QT3XJBK5/F02S9JJAAP4/error_log.png
    const filters =
      options.filters &&
      Object.entries(options.filters).reduce(
        (ret, [key, value]) => ({
          ...ret,
          [key]: allowPartialMatch.includes(key)
            ? { $regex: value, $options: "i" }
            : value,
        }),
        {}
      );
    const query = { ...options, filters };
    return await paginate<RedeemDocument>(RedeemModel, query);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

redeem.controller:

```
export async function listRedeemsHandler(
  req: Request<{}, {}, {}, { filters: string; page: string; sort: string }>,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) {
  try {
    const { query } = req;

    const filters = JSON.parse(
      query.filters || "{}"
    ) as FilterQuery<RedeemDocument>;
    const sort = JSON.parse(query.sort || "{}") as {
      [key: string]: SortValues;
    };

    const data = await listRedeems({
      filters,
      page: parseInt(query.page) || 1,
      sort,
    });
    return res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
}
```

Here You Are the HTTP Request sent (Only filters Crashes):

> {{base_url}}/redeem?page=1&sort={"updatedAt": "-1"}&filters={"amount":
> 50}

and Here You Are the Error Log:

[Here You Are the Log's Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh8tV.png)